# Select object by literal text name in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Consider this is a standard Linq

```
from q in SomeQuery select new SomeObject { SomeKey = q.SomeKey }
```

What if the `Somekey` is a text I got from other place, then the code like this is not going to work

```
string key = "SomeKey";
from q in SomeQuery select new SomeObject { key = q[key] }
```

I hope you got my idea. Please tell me a correct way to write Linq, when I know the property by a text string.

Comment: can you explain more? what is `SomeObject`? what type is `q`?

Comment: `q[key]` doesn't make much sense. And a key/key name-conflict can easily be avoided.

Comment: Most time I use Linq to Azure table, so the `SomeObject` is `TableServiceEntity`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general case you are looking for something like

```
var key = "SomeKey";
from q in SomeQuery select new SomeObject { 
    SomeKey = q.GetType().GetProperty("key").GetValue(q, null)
};
```

This fetches the value of a property known at runtime with reflection, but I find it hard to recommend code like this. Let's see why.

1. First of all, it's not possible to dynamically define the *name* of the property in the anonymous type we are selecting (here, I have hardcoded it as `SomeKey`). Anonymous types may not have a name, but they are types like any other and in a language like C# this means that their members have to be known at compile time. So it would be theoretically impossible to create the anonymous type at runtime¹. Even if it were possible to do it, you could not access the properties on the anonymous type without, again, using reflection.
2. It does not make much sense to "store the name of the information" as a property name (which is static) when you *already* have it in a variable (which is dynamic). If you want to pass a reference around, pass the contents of `key`.
3. If you want to associate string keys with values it makes sense to use a dynamic structure as your backing store. For example, if `SomeQuery` is `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>` then you could simply do `SomeKey = q[key]`. If not, then perhaps it should have been?
4. If for some reason you need all this dynamism, then a reasonable first approach would be to look into using [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx).

Comment: I know `from q in SomeQuery select q` will fetch all data, so normally I use `select new some{some=some}` to fetch only the data I need. Can I ask, from your approach, will it also fetch all data, then just return the needed, or it will only fetch the data that needed?

Comment: @EricYin: Are you referring to LINQ to objects or something else? This will *only* work with LINQ to objects, as you cannot use reflection when targeting an `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 2):

```
from q in SomeQuery select 
new SomeObject { key = q.GetType().GetProperty(key).GetValue(q) }
```

Comment: I know the last part, the GetType/GetProperty/GetValue way. But if you consider `key` is a string, you cannot put value to a string

Comment: @EricYin I don't get what you mean

Comment: Besides using [reflection as shown by @Magnus](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9981535/50776) you could also try [FastMember](http://code.google.com/p/fast-member/) which will be faster for that kind of work.

Comment: @EricYin: What the above code does is it will try to retrieve a property with the name as provided by `key`. This seems to be what you were asking for. If not can you expand your question in more detail what exactly you expect to happen?

Comment: ohh, its inside object, i forget that, my bad.